# Alignment problem (3 minipages in figure)

Tags: captions, minipage

I am new to LaTeX and I have to recreate a document in LaTeX for my course. But I found problem.
Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
  \centering\includegraphics[width=3cm]{box.eps}
  \captionof{figure}{Obrazek}\label{obr4}
 \end{minipage}%
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.20\textwidth}
  A jeste nejaky text mezi obrazkem a tabulkou.
 \end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.44\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
   \hline
   Den & Datum \\
   \hline
   \hline
   Pondeli & 14.\,6. \\
   Utery & 14.\,5. \\
   Streda & 14.\,3. \\
   Ctvrtek & 14.\,2. \\
   Patek & 14.\,9. \\
   \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \captionof{table}{Tabulka vedle obrazku}\label{tab1}
 \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How it looks and how it have to look:
[image]
Problem description:
In my work, bottom line of text (in second minipage) is lower than captions of picture and table and I am not able to find out why.
Please review my code or ask any other questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which is compilable. Your current code is missing important things like `\documentclass` and relevant packages to define commands like `\includegraphics` and `\captionof`.

Comment: please don't edit a question to add an answer it makes a mess of the archival version of the site,  also the `%`  removing a horizontal inter-word space, not changing the vertical alignment.

Answer (score 1):

The `\label` are affecting the vertical alignment, place them *inside* the caption:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
  \centering\includegraphics[width=3cm]{box.eps}
  \captionof{figure}{Obrazek\label{obr4}}
 \end{minipage}%
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.20\textwidth}
  A jeste nejaky text mezi obrazkem a tabulkou.
 \end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.44\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
   \hline
   Den & Datum \\
   \hline
   \hline
   Pondeli & 14.\,6. \\
   Utery & 14.\,5. \\
   Streda & 14.\,3. \\
   Ctvrtek & 14.\,2. \\
   Patek & 14.\,9. \\
   \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \captionof{table}{Tabulka vedle obrazku\label{tab1}}
 \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```